# Why relativize produces "../file_name" when both files are in the same folder?

Tags: java, path, nio

I know there were at least two similar questions answered already, but I still struggle with understanding the `relativize()` method.

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("f1.txt");
Path p2 = Paths.get("f2.txt");
out.println(p1.relativize(p2)); // ../f2.txt
out.println(p2.relativize(p1)); // ../f1.txt
```

If I have two files in the same directory (`f1.txt` and `f2.txt`), why does `relativize()` produces `../f2.txt` and `../f1.txt` respectively? Where did the `../` come? I mean, the symbol `../` makes you go up to the parent folder of the folder you are currently in, right? So `p1.relativize(p2)` producing result `../f2.txt` basically says "To find `f2.txt` go outside the current folder". But that doesn't make any sense. Reproducing the similar folder structure and navigating with `cd` I do not need to add `../` to access the file within the same folder which I am currently in. All I need is to enter the file name. Please explain

Comment: From the docs: [Relativization is the inverse of resolution](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html#relativize(java.nio.file.Path)), so it seems that it can be used to *"undo"* the `Path.resolve()` as is shown in the example: `p.relativize(p.resolve(q)).equals(q)`

Comment: Try with `Path p1 = Paths.get("./");`  and `Path p2 = Paths.get("f2.txt");`. You may notice the reason.

Answer (score -1):

So let me help you with an example. First, let me mention that you don't care about the parent folder.

You care about the path that is relative between the two paths. In other words how to access the second path from the first.

E.g.

```
Path path = Paths.get("/folder1/folder2/file");
Path path2 = Paths.get("/folder1/folder3/file2");
System.out.println((path.relativize(path2)));
System.out.println((path2.relativize(path)));
```

The output is:
`../../folder3/file2`
`../../folder2/file`

For your example, if you have the f1 and you want the f2 the relative paths go from the ../ to reach the f2 and vise versa.

Comment: Well, yes, your example makes sense: "To get to `file2` folder, exit to parent `folder2` (that's one `../`), then exit to parent `folder1` (second `../`). You're now in `folder1`. From here enter `folder3` and then enter `file2` inside". Thus `../../folder3/file2` if fairly logical. But I still haven't figured out the logic with accessing files inside the same folder while using `../`

Comment: I think that if we think about it in a Linux manner, then this does not make sense. But In a file structure manner, it kinda does. In my perspective and as I read the java docs.